# NHibernate select with Query Over optimization for user roles base case

Tags: c#, linq, hibernate

I have a complicated select procedure that I solved with a 5 query select, so I am posting it here to get suggestions on how I can shorten it up a bit.  I am hoping that someone can help me make it a single query select.
I'm using nhibernate query over here.

I have 7 tables which are

- `t_user`
- `t_category`
- `t_event`
- `t_announcement`
- `t_event_follower`
- `t_event_register`
- `t_event_subcribe`

I will represent them in the classes below:

```
class User {
  int id;
  string username;
  IList<Registration> registrations;
  IList<Category> subscribes;
  IList<Event> follows;
}

class Category {
  int id;
  string description;
  IList<User> subscribers;
}

class Event{
  int id;
  string title;
  Category category;
  IList<Registration> registrations;
  IList<User> followers;
  IList<Announcement> announcements;
}

class Announcement {
  int id;
  string title;
  Event event;
  bool isForFollower;
  bool isForRegister;
  bool isForSubscriber;
}

class Registration {
  int id;
  Event event;
  User user;
  string additionalInfo;
  RegistrationStatus status;
}

enum UserRole {
  PUBLIC,
  FOLLOWER,
  SUBSCRIBER,
  REGISTERED
}
```

The goal is to show all announcements in 1 event based on user roles on that event.  What I had done first is populate user role in list with the code below:

```
User requester = _userRepo.SearchBy(username); // 1 query for user detail

// 3 lazy load objects make nhibernate to load the object from db, i assume it takes 3 query select if objects haven't load in session
bool isFollower = requester.Follows.Any(eventz => eventz.Id == eventId);
bool isSubscriber = requester.Subscribes.Any(category => category.Events.Any(eventz => eventz.Id == eventId));
bool isRegistered = requester.Registrations.Any(registration => registration.Event.Id == eventId);
var userRoleList= new List<UserRole>();

if (isFollower) userRoleList.Add(UserRole.FOLLOWER);
if (isSubscriber) userRoleList.Add(UserRole.SUBSCRIBER);
if (isRegistered) userRoleList.Add(UserRole.REGISTERED);
```

last with code in repository layer below i create dynamic disjunction for query over :

```
Disjunction filterRestriction = Restrictions.Disjunction();
// this condition to select announcement which is for public not specific
filterRestriction.Add(Restrictions.Where<Announcement>(a => a.IsForFollower == false
                                                            && a.IsForSubscriber == false
                                                            && a.IsForRegistered == false));

foreach (UserRole role in userRoleList)
{
    switch (role)
    {
        case UserRole.FOLLOWER:
            filterRestriction.Add(Restrictions.Where<Announcement>(a => a.IsForFollower));
            break;
        case UserRole.SUBSCRIBER:
            filterRestriction.Add(Restrictions.Where<Announcement>(a => a.IsForSubscriber));
            break;
        case UserRole.REGISTERED:
            filterRestriction.Add(Restrictions.Where<Announcement>(a => a.IsForRegistered));
            break;
    }
}
//this is the last query transaction, so total 5 times select from db CMIIW, 
return _session.QueryOver<Announcement>()
               .Where(filterRestriction)
               .And(a => a.Event.Id == id)
               .List();
```

In the above code, the query result will show public announcement plus specific announcement based on role that user have in related event.

I admit this is the simplest solution I could think to solve the case.  Could someone give a suggestion or rework this just by 1 simple operation with query over or just remake it with better query?

Comment: Are you stuck with an NHibernate solution? Can you do a stored procedure/view/dynamic sql statement instead?

Comment: nope, i knew there is a lot of alternatives like you said.. I just wanna get a better solution with nhibernate api. Because i lack of experience with nhibernate api, hoping someone else can provide something different or maybe a better point of view for this case.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you mean by transaction, but if your only goal is to make all queries in one transaction, why not use NHibernate transaction support? [Use of implicit transactions is discouraged](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof/learn/alert/DoNotUseImplicitTransactions) according to NHibernate blog post. But I probably misunderstood you, you probably already have one transaction, and what you really want is to make fewer database queries in it, right?

Comment: That's right, I want to make it to be a fewer query as for now it does 5 select to db. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

If this is a web application, you can use an HttpModule to do your session management. Begin every web request by opening a session and beginning a transaction. At the end of every web request, commit the transaction and close the session.

As long as you're wrapping all the hits to the database in a single transaction, you don't need to worry about efficiency too much.

Comment: Yes, I've been applying this module you talked about in every project. The problem is I want to know if there is a way to make my queries simpler than like mine above?